# cygwin run a command instead of cmd python

Tags: python, cygwin, cmd, subprocess

I have a python GUI and i want to run a shell command which you cannot do using windows cmd
i have installed cygwin and i was wondering how i would go about running cygwin instead of the windows cmd. I am wanting to use subprocess and get the results of the .sh file
but my code

```
subprocess.check_output("./listChains.sh < 2p31protein.pdb")
```

This will run it in cmd and as windows will not recognize it, it will not work, so how can i get it to run in cygwin instead of cmd

Answer (score 2):

Execute a cygwin shell (e.g. `bash`) and have it run your script, instead of running your script directly:

```
subprocess.check_output("C:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe ./listChains.sh < 2p31protein.pdb")
```

Alternatively, associate the `.sh` filetype extension to open with `bash.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Using python sub-process to run a cygwin executable requires that the ./bin directory with `cygwin1.dll` be on the Windows path. `cygwin1.dll` exposes cygwin executables to Windows, allowing them to run in Windows command line and be called by Python sub-process.